# Ubuntu on an Asus X205 Subnotebook?

Tags: system-installation, uefi, laptop, asus, 32-bit

Anybody succeed in loading Ubuntu on the new [Asus X205](https://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_EeeBook_X205TA/) subnotebook? I am not certain if the UEFI is 32 bits or 64 bits.

Comment: I've got to stage 3 of a similar guide for the [Asus Transformer Book T100TA](http://www.jfwhome.com/2014/03/07/perfect-ubuntu-or-other-linux-on-the-asus-transformer-book-t100/) However, the WiFi is unsupported. I did find a page with drivers for the series of adapter, but I've been unable to find one which works. You can find those in part of of the link above (minus the name of the .bin file the person provides) From [this](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Supported_devices) page I have determined that it's untested at best. In Windows, the WiFi is reported as BRCM433X.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some success with installing linux on this laptop. The UEFI is 32-bit, and so I had to compile a 32-bit UEFI grub to boot. The wireless card in this laptop is also unsupported currently. It's supported in android, but not in the current Broadcom linux drivers.